# R subset data by multiple conditions on every row

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I got a very large dataset which contains many columns and rows. Not every co-worker is allowed to see all data. Based on the dataframe `Data_locatie` I want to subset my original dataframe `DF`. The column `acces` tells me if the co-worker may see this combination yes(=1) or no(=0). I made a reproducible example which you can use.

```
CityChargeSessions <-c("Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Amsterdam","Beverwaard","De meern","De Meern","De Meern","Den Haag","Den Haag")
RegionAbbreviation  <- c("G4", "G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4")
Provider<- c("ALLEGO","Essent","EVBOX","Nuon","EVBOX","EVnet","Ballast Nedam", "Nuon","Alfen","EVnet")
acces<- c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0)

Data_locatie<- data.frame(CityChargeSessions,RegionAbbreviation,Provider,acces)

CityChargeSessions <-c("Amsterdam" ,"Amsterdam" ,"Den Haag" , "Den Haag"  ,"Rotterdam", "Rotterdam", "Rotterdam", "Utrecht"  , "Utrecht"  )
RegionAbbreviation  <- c("G4", "G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4","G4")
Provider <- c("Essent","Nuon","Alfen","EVnet","Alfen","EVBOX", "EVnet","Ballast Nedam", "EVnet")
kWh<- c(3366231.03, 7547896.10, 2535700.80,  245951.82,   62004.86, 3074192.86,  221362.13, 1272956.51,  281451.94)

DF<- data.frame(CityChargeSessions,RegionAbbreviation,Provider,kWh)
```

My expected output is:

```
CityChargeSessions <-c("Amsterdam" ,"Den Haag")
RegionAbbreviation  <- c("G4", "G4")
Provider <- c("Essent","Alfen ")
kWh<- c(3366231.03, 2535700.80)


expected_output<- data.frame(CityChargeSessions,RegionAbbreviation,Provider,kWh)
```

Could you help me out?

Thanks for your help!

Martijn

Comment: What is the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the data table and do the following:

```
require(data.table)    
setDT(Data_locatie)
setkey(Data_locatie, "CityChargeSessions", "RegionAbbreviation", "Provider")
setDT(DF)
setkey(DF, "CityChargeSessions", "RegionAbbreviation", "Provider")

allowed_combinations <- DF[Data_locatie[acces==1], nomatch=0][, acces:=NULL]
not_allowed_combinations <- DF[Data_locatie[acces==0], nomatch=0][, acces:=NULL]
```

Comment: Thanks this is excatly were I was looking for!!

Comment: Glad to hear it :)